# use of (a,b) -> a-b lambda function java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, collections, java-8

hlo
i'm always confuse why we use (a,b) -> a-b for sorting.

example-

> Collections.sort(list, (a, b) -> { return (a[1] - b[1]); });
>
> PriorityQueue MaxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>((a,b) -> a-b);

i'm really confused, i try to understand the flow of this statement by bebugging of code.

```
ArrayList<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
list.add(new int[] { start[i], end[i] });
}
Collections.sort(list, (a, b) -> {
return (a[1] - b[1]);
});

int count = 1;
int[] x = list.get(0);
for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
int[] res = list.get(i);
if (x[1] < res[0]) {
count += 1;
x = res;
}
}
return count;
}
```

if someone has a better way to understand this please help me.

Comment: a - b gets you a valid comparasion result. 0 -> equal, positive -> a > b, negative -> a < b

Comment: if `a[1] - b[1]` is less than 0, that means `a[1]` is smaller than `b[1]`; similarly, if `a[1] - b[1]` is greater than 0, that means `a[1]` is greater than `b[1]`; if `a[1] - b[1]` is 0, that means `a[1]` is equal to `b[1]`

Comment: The basic reason is that you are not guaranteed that `<` will compare the way you want it to when doing the sort, so you need to provide code for that.

Comment: @DownloadPizza - It is not necessarily valid.  If `a` and `b` are (say) `int` and the values can be any integer, then this implementation can give incorrect answers.

Comment: @StephenC You are correct, I had forgotten java does not check for underflow by default

Comment: A correct implementation would be `(a, b) -> Integer.compare(a[1], b[1])` in the first case and `(a, b) -> Integer.compare(a, b)` in the second.

Comment: @DownloadPizza is it only applicable for primate data type or we can use it both for non primitive or primitive.

Comment: Is what applicable?  The broken implementations in your example?  Strictly speaking they are not applicable for any types.  (They would be inapplicable for floating point types for other reasons ...)

Comment: @ShantiLalPrajapat it is only applicable to things you can subtract. It uses the rules of maths to provide an ordering.

Comment: @StephenC sorry but i'm not getting your point. what is the purpose of using Integer.compare(a,b).

Comment: @ShantiLalPrajapat however the positive equal negative rule is how comparasions work, so if you sort some object you need to return an integer that represents the ordering of the object (0 = equal and so on)

Comment: @DownloadPizza please correct me if i'm wrong. it's like compreTo() method from string class where the negative shows the second one is greather and positive integer shows first one is greather and zero shows that both are equal.

Comment: @ShantiLalPrajapat Exactly like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *goal* of the lambda `(a,b) -> a-b` is to produce a number that satisfies the `Comparator` contract:

- if `a` less than `b` - return a negative result
- if `a` equals `b` - return zero
- if `a` greater than `b` - return a positive result.

The value returned by the `Comparator` is used by `sort` to compare pairs of elements (numbers) in the collection to decide which is bigger.

**The problem** is that `a - b` doesn't work properly for Java integer types<sup>1</sup>.  In some cases, `a - b` will overflow and you will get a result with the wrong sign.  For example, if `a` is `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `b` is a positive integer, then `a - b` will be positive when it should be negative.

(This is a fairly common mistake, that even relatively experienced programmers make ... though hopefully, only once.)

By contrast, the `Integer.compare(int, int)` method gives the correct answer ... for all possible arguments.  So better (i.e. more correct) solutions would be:

```
Collections.sort(list, (a, b) -> Integer.compare(a[1], b[1]));

PriorityQueue<Integer> MaxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(Integer::compare);
```

---

<sup>1 - In fact, for any kind of integer type where overflow doesn't trigger an exception of some kind.  And for floating point types, there are different gotchas.</sup>

Comment: Always use the corresponding compare method in wrapper class to compare. Integer.compare or Long.compare etc

Comment: so for String comparision what i can used to sort. In that case can i use compareTo or what mehtod.

Comment: You can use `(a, b) -> a.compareTo(b)`.  Or call `Compator.naturalOrder()` to generate a `Comparator<String>`.  There isn't a static `String.compare(String,String)` method, so `String::compare` isn't an option.

Comment: @StephenC thanks for your explanation. now i clearly understand this.

Comment: Well, `String::compareTo` would work, but there is no sense in implementing a new `Comparator` for a type that has a natural order anyway. Just use `new PriorityQueue<>()` resp. `Collections.sort(list);` for `String`. The same applies to the `PriorityQueue<Integer>`; just use the default constructor. You only need a `Comparator` for types without a natural order, like the `int[]`, or when you want a different order than the natural order.